# Calculating outer corner radius for concentric rounded corners of a border

Tags: math, geometry

I have rectangle with a border.
The rectangle is 50x50 with a corner radius of 5.

When using the same corner radius for the border the result is:

[image: wrong border corner radius]

But I actually need something like this:

[image: correct border corner radius]

How to calculate the border corner radius?
Can this be calculated somehow with only the border width and corner radius?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to have both corner-curves concentric use

```
outerradius = cornerradius + borderwidth
```

This will get the straight parts start and end in parallel at the same (horizontal or vertical) position, i.e. the center of both quarter-circles is at the same point.

Comment: realized it myself after thinking about it for a moment, but because i am no math or geometry guy i assumed there is some fancy math behind it :D

Comment: I know what you mean. And judging from the fact that I still get an upvote about once a year, this (answer and question) seems to be helpful to more people... ;-) @GabrielStein